# Open tickets between 2 dates

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm trying to find the open tickets, that are open between may 1st 2012 and may 30th 2012 for that day.

So, I should get: May 1st : 0, May 2nd 0, 3rd : 2

But what I'm getting currently is May 1st: 2, 2nd: 2, 3rd:2 then start to go up every 3 days

data :

```
CREATE TABLE bugs
(
    BUG_ID          NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    REPORTED_DATE   DATE NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPTION     VARCHAR2(20),
    PRIORITY        NUMBER(2),
    ASSIGNED_TO     VARCHAR2(10),
    CLOSED_DATE     DATE,
    NOTE            VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO BUGS VALUES (1230, '25-APR-12', NULL, 3, 'Team 3', '28-APR-12', NULL); 
INSERT INTO BUGS VALUES (1231, '29-APR-12', NULL, 1, 'Team 1', '29-APR-12', NULL); 
INSERT INTO BUGS VALUES (1232, '03-MAY-12', NULL, 1, 'Team 1', '03-MAY-12', NULL); 
INSERT INTO BUGS VALUES (1233, '03-MAY-12', NULL, 1, 'Team 3', '08-MAY-12', NULL);
INSERT INTO BUGS VALUES (1234, '04-MAY-12', NULL, 2, 'Team 5', '15-MAY-12', NULL);
INSERT INTO BUGS VALUES (1235, '04-MAY-12', NULL, 2, 'Team 1',  NULL,       NULL);
INSERT INTO BUGS VALUES (1236, '05-MAY-12', NULL, 1, 'Team 2', '06-MAY-12', NULL);
INSERT INTO BUGS VALUES (1237, '05-MAY-12', NULL, 3, 'Team 3', '10-MAY-12', NULL);
INSERT INTO BUGS VALUES (1238, '09-MAY-12', NULL, 4, 'Team 5', '16-MAY-12', NULL);
INSERT INTO BUGS VALUES (1239, '09-MAY-12', NULL, 5, 'Team 6',  NULL,       NULL);
INSERT INTO BUGS VALUES (1240, '12-MAY-12', NULL, 5, 'Team 2', '30-MAY-12', NULL);
INSERT INTO BUGS VALUES (1241, '12-MAY-12', NULL, 1, 'Team 1', '12-MAY-12', NULL);
INSERT INTO BUGS VALUES (1242, '13-MAY-12', NULL, 4, 'Team 4', '20-MAY-12', NULL);
INSERT INTO BUGS VALUES (1243, '15-MAY-12', NULL, 4, 'Team 3', '01-AUG-12', NULL);
INSERT INTO BUGS VALUES (1244, '15-MAY-12', NULL, 2, 'Team 4', '20-MAY-12', NULL);
INSERT INTO BUGS VALUES (1245, '20-MAY-12', NULL, 2, 'Team 4',  NULL,       NULL);
INSERT INTO BUGS VALUES (1246, '22-MAY-12', NULL, 2, 'Team 4', '23-MAY-12', NULL);
INSERT INTO BUGS VALUES (1247, '25-MAY-12', NULL, 2, 'Team 1', '29-MAY-12', NULL);
INSERT INTO BUGS VALUES (1248, '30-MAY-12', NULL, 1, 'Team 1', '01-JUN-12', NULL);
INSERT INTO BUGS VALUES (1249, '05-JUN-12', NULL, 1, 'Team 2', '07-JUN-12', NULL);
COMMIT;
```

My code so far:

```
DECLARE
  v_date bugs.closed_date%type     := '01-may-12';
  v_end_date bugs.closed_date%type := '20-may-12';
  v_openbugs NUMBER(10);
BEGIN
  WHILE v_date <= v_end_date
  LOOP
    SELECT COUNT(bug_id)
    INTO v_openbugs
    FROM bugs
    WHERE bugs.reported_date < v_date
    AND v_date > bugs.closed_date;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_date ||'   '|| v_openbugs);
    v_date := v_date + 1;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

I need to do this in PL/SQL.

Comment: I've edited out your answer that you placed in the question. The full text is within [the revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16049828/revisions), please post this as an answer to your own question rather than editing the question. I've done this at the moment but please comment under this comment when you've done so and I'll delete the answer and the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Answer I got

```
DECLARE
  v_date bugs.closed_date%type     := '01-may-12';
  v_end_date bugs.closed_date%type := '31-may-12';
  v_openbugs NUMBER(10);
  v_maxbug number(10):=0;
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Date' ||'   '|| 'Open bugs');
  WHILE v_date <= v_end_date
  LOOP
    SELECT COUNT(bug_id)
    INTO v_openbugs
    FROM bugs
    WHERE bugs.reported_date <= to_date(v_date)
    AND nvl(bugs.closed_date,'31-may-12') >= to_date(v_date);
   if v_maxbug < v_openbugs then v_maxbug:=v_openbugs; end if;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_date ||'   '|| v_openbugs);
    v_date := v_date + 1;
  END LOOP;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('===========================');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('the max number of open bugs is:'|| v_maxbug);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this just with SQL:

```
WITH DAYS AS
    (SELECT 
        TO_DATE('06/01/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY') - ROWNUM D
    FROM
        DUAL
    WHERE ROWNUM < 32)
SELECT
    DAYS.D,
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN B.REPORTED_DATE IS NULL THEN 
            0 
        ELSE 
            1 
        END)
FROM
    DAYS 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN BUGS B
    ON (DAYS.D BETWEEN B.REPORTED_DATE AND NVL(CLOSED_DATE, DAYS.D))
GROUP BY DAYS.D
ORDER BY DAYS.D ASC
```

If you are going to make this an automatic report then I would pass the dates as an argument and store the result in a cursor and have the calling procedure format the output as required.

Comment: Thanks John D I'm doing this for a school project and i need to use pl/sql :(